# Solve for Sides of a 5-Sided Irregular Polygon

Tags: geometry, polygons

I have a 5-sided irregular polygon and I know the lengths of 4 of its 5 sides and 2 of its 5 angles. Is there a way to know the length of the 5th side using this information?

Comment: If, in pentagon $ABCDE$, you know $|\overline{AB}|$, $|\overline{BC}|$, $|\overline{CD}|$ and $\angle B$ and $\angle C$, then you have completely determined a sub-quadrilateral $ABCD$. However, you only have one more known length, either $|\overline{DE}|$ or $|\overline{AE}|$ (it doesn't matter which). So, effectively, you know the lengths of two sides of $\triangle DEA$; this is not enough information to determine where point $E$ lies, and therefore not enough information to determine the length of the third side of that triangle (which is the fifth side of the pentagon).

Comment: in general use need $(2n-3)$ pieces of information to solve an n-gon, you are one piece short.