# What is the minimum information needed to solve a 5 sided irregular polygon?

Tags: geometry

For example, for a triangle all you need is an angle and the length of one side, and using that you can solve for the rest of the trianlge’s dimensions.

Comment: For a triangle, you need three elements !

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329160/solve-for-sides-of-a-5-sided-irregular-polygon

Comment: The full rule for even a triangle is a little complicated: three elements suffice in most cases, but not if they are three angles, and not in some cases if they are two sides and a non-included angle (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_of_triangles#Solving_plane_triangles).

Answer (score 0):

Let the polygon be $ABCDE$.

Seven elements are often sufficient. For example, it would suffice to know any 4 sides together with the 3 included angles, eg to know lengths $AB$, $BC$, $CD$ and $DE$ and angles $B$, $C$ and $D$.

Why?  Because lengths $AB$ and $BC$ and $\angle B$ determine triangle $ABC$, and similarly for triangles $BCD$ and $CDE$. The triangles together fix the position of $E$ relative to $A$, so the whole polygon is determined.

On the other hand the following case shows that even eight elements could be insufficient.  Suppose $\angle A = \angle B = \angle C = 90^o$, $\angle D = \angle E = 45^o$, $AB = 2$; $CD=1$; $DE = \sqrt{2}$.  Then the lengths of $AE$ and $BC$, which are parallel, are indeterminate.